# SQL Select values starting with a capital letter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a varchar type column. I want to select values from this column which start with a capital letter only.

For example

MyTable

```
Col1          Col2

Argentina     2
Brasil        3
uruguay       4
```

I want my select query to return:

```
Argentina
Brasil
```

Comment: Please do not add the answer to your question; accepting the answer which worked for you is sufficient.

Comment: Ok @Matt , Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a bit of a pain.  You can use `ASCII()` or `COLLATE`, but these depend on how the data is stored.  For `varchar()` and `char()`, this will work:

```
where ASCII(left(col1, 1)) between ASCII('A') and ASCII('Z')
```

Comment: The left function requires 2 argument(s).

Comment: Old but Gold!!!

Answer (score 1):

select Col1 from MyTable where Col1 like '[A-Z]%'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In our collation Z is located between S and T for example and your like ignores TUVXYZ (and bunch of diacritics) - not good answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30127564)

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use `UPPER` AND `COLLATE` Functions to do this.

For E.g:

```
create table #a (text varchar(10))

insert into #a values ('HAI'),('Hai'),('hai'),('44A')

select *from #a where substring([text],1,1) = substring(Upper([text]),1,1) collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
                                            AND substring([text],1,1) like '[A-Z]%'
```

Comment: That would also return strings that don't start with a letter

Comment: I'd have just used not equal to the lower case version instead

Answer (score 0):

```
 With TestData As
    (
    Select '012324' As Name
    Union All Select 'ABC'
    Union All Select 'abc'
    Union All Select 'aBc'
    Union All Select 'ABé'
    Union All Select 'ABÉ'
    )
Select *
 From TestData
Where Name = UPPER(Name) Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

hope this will help

Comment: Your example executes as  012324, ABC, ABÉ  that's a failure for "which starts with a capital letter"  (using SQL Server 2014)